# mount and remount a mysql database?

Tags: mysql, mount

Is there the equivalent of a device unmount / mount for a mysql database?

My server has around 15 databases, of which maybe 10 are rarely used, and only on demand if I have to do some fixes on apps I have been working.

So the idea is to unmount the unused databases until I need them. This should free some resources?

I know I can dump them into a file and reload them, but that has a 'cumbersome' feeling to me and I was wondering if such a mount/unmount exists. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. If they're truly not being used, overhead resource utilization is very minimal, so I wouldn't worry about it if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing, because SQL databases are slightly differs from filesystems.
However, MySQL have resource management system, so it is not uses resources if it is not needed.

Especially databases are just "folders" so they are not allocates too much memory. The main things in the memory are a tables. But, because MySQL has some transactional features, they are not uses too much resource too if they are not used.

So, in short: you can do anything with databases if you are sure applications willn't like use them. I sometimes do mysql_check on a production servers production database and it can do its job without problems (excluded some warnings about existing connections).